# Intent para abrir link no browser não funciona

Tags: android, android-intent

Como faço para fazer com que meu botão envie o usuário para um link?

```
String url = "LINK";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

tentei desta forma porém não funcionou

Comment: a forma esta certa mas no lugar do link é o link mesmo...  it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        it.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.whatsapp.com"));

ou  String url = "http://www.whatsapp.com"  e depois 
  it.setData(Uri.parse(url ));

Comment: Eu sei, eu tirei o link , obrigado amigo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O seu código está correto.

O que deve estar a acontecer é estar a usar um URL sem o protocolo, do tipo "google.com".

O URL deve incluir o protocolo "http://" ou "https://".

```
String url = "http://google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Você pode criar um método que garanta que o link tenha o protocolo adicionado:

```
public static browseTo(String url){

    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```